# Where do I put "business logic"?

Tags: abp

I have built out an abp.io application following the Bookstore demo/documentation.

I have a "Location" Entity(?) that has several address fields (Address, City, State, Zip, etc).

It also had Latitude and Longitude fields. In order to determine the Lat and Long, I have to hit an external API once the Location is created or updated.

Where and how do I create this logic?

As far as I can figure out, I have to do the following upon creation or update:

- Save the Address data to the database
- Pass the Address data to my business logic
- Use that data to make the external API call to grab the Lat and Long
- Use the Lat and Long that are returned to update those fields for the Location in the database

I have the code working that will get me the Lat and Long. I just don't know how to call it and then how to update the database entry with it.

Note, this is using abp.io with Angular and EFC (MS SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make this process more robust and easier by taking advantage of abp.
For example, after the location is created, updated or deleted, you can publish an event and then subscribe.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Local-Event-Bus#inside-entity-aggregate-root-classes

Also, in your case, if location's isRequired is true, you can issue an event when the asset change is successfully saved to the database.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Local-Event-Bus#events-with-past-tense

Pub/Sub is used in many places within the ABP repo. For example one of them => https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/docs/src/Volo.Docs.Domain/Volo/Docs/Documents/FullSearch/Elastic/DocumentChangedEventHandler.cs

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. Those links helped out greatly!